# Android display GPS status on button when enabled or disabled

Tags: android, gps

If GPS is off and application is launched a alert box with "GPS Settings and "Cancel" button will appear. If user chooses "GPS Settings" and enables the GPS, the button on the MainActivity displays "GPS is on" instead of "GPS is OFF.Turn it On". And if GPS is on and application is launched, it will display "GPS is on" . Now while in application if user decides to enable or disable the GPS, he simply clicks the button that is displaying the GPS status and it will redirects him to GPS Settings and when he enables or disables the GPS and return back, the button must display the current GPS Status.

---

Now the only part troubling me is when GPS is off and application is launched and user enables it through the alert box,the GPS Status on button is not changing,rest its working fine.Please guide me

```
GPSState = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bGPSstate);
        boolean isGPSEnabled = false;
// Declaring a Location Manager
        LocationManager locationManager;

        locationManager = (LocationManager) getApplicationContext()
                .getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

        // getting GPS status
        isGPSEnabled = locationManager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
if (!isGPSEnabled) {
            // no GPS provider is enabled
            // displaying GPS status on the button and and opening GPS activity
            GPSState.setText("GPS is off.turn it on");
            GPSState.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    startActivityForResult(
                            new Intent(
                                    android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS),
                            REQUESTCODE);

                }
            });
// creating alertdialog
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(c);

            builder.setTitle("Settings");
            builder.setMessage("Enable GPS for the Application");

            builder.setPositiveButton("GPS Setting",

            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    startActivity(new Intent(
                            android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS));

                    dialog.dismiss();
                }

            });

            builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                            new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                                    .setTitle("How to use Application")
                                    .setMessage(
                                            "You must enable the GPS in order to use this application. Press Activate and then press Power Button twice in order to send the alert message to the selected contacts")
                                    .setNeutralButton(
                                            "OK",
                                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                                                @Override
                                                public void onClick(
                                                        DialogInterface dialog,
                                                        int which) {
                                                    // do something // for
                                                    // returning back to //
                                                    // application
                                                    dialog.cancel();

                                                }
                                            }).show();
                            dialog.dismiss();

                        }
                    });

            builder.show();

        } else {

        }
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        boolean isGPSEnabled = false;
        GPSState = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bGPSstate);
        LocationManager locationManager;
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getApplicationContext()
                .getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        isGPSEnabled = locationManager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        if (!isGPSEnabled)
            GPSState.setText("GPS is off.Turn it on");
        else
            GPSState.setText("GPS is on");
```

Comment: You should check gps status in onResume() of activity and update your button there also.

Comment: how shall i mark you as an answer ?

Comment: i will answer this question as your ans is this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check gps status in onResume() of activity and update your button there.